# Given the following joint density function; find the expectation of $h(x,y)=2x+5y$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, correlation, marginal-distribution

Let $f(x,y) = c(2x+y)$ ; $0<x<2$; and $0<y<3$ and $0$ otherwise

Calculate:

$(i)$ Value of $c$

$(ii)$ Obtain Marginal PDF's of both $X$ and $Y$

$(iii)$ find the expectation of $h(x,y)=2x+5y$

$(iv)$ find the correlation coefficient

My working:

$Part (i)$

I have found value of $c=\frac{1}{21}$

$Part (ii)$

I have found marginal PDF's of $X$ and $Y$ respectively to be the following:

$f_X(x) =\frac{1}{21}\times(6x+9/2)$

$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{21}\times(2y+4)$

$Part (iii)$:

This is where I am stuck. I dont know how to find expectation of a function; As far as I know we find expectation of a random variable.

$Part (iv)$ I dont even know where to begin for this at all.

can anyone guide me please. It will be quite helpful

Comment: Your answers to I and ii are correct.  In general, $E[g(X)] = \int g(X) f_X(x) dx$, and this extends to multiple variables.

Comment: Part (i) and (ii) are correct. For part (iii), there are lots of way to do it. You can use some known results on expectation. For example $E(2X+5Y) = 2E(X)+5E(Y)$ and you know how to find $EX$ and $EY$ since you know their density functions form (ii). You can also use definition $E(h(x,y)) = \int_x\int_y h(x,y)f(x,y)dyed$, where $f(x,y)$ is joint distribution of $X,Y$ (this is known). For part (iv), you need to find covariance first and then compute correlation. It's all about definition and computation.

Comment: I get $230/21$ for iii.  For iv, use the definition of correlation coefficient.

Comment: Yes I also got the same answer. I am having trouble in correlation coefficient, I am new to this topic. A bit more help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part iv, use the formula $\rho(X,Y)=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$. All that remains is to do about 5 integrals.

$E(X)=\int_0^2\frac x{21}\left(6x+\frac92\right)dx=\frac{25}{21}$

$E(Y)=\int_0^3\frac y{21}(2y+4)dy=\frac{12}7$

$\begin{split}E(XY)&=\int_0^3\int_0^2\frac{xy}{21}(2x+y)dxdy\\
&=\int_0^3\frac{y(6y+16)}{63}dy=2\end{split}$

$Cov(X,Y)=2-\frac{25}{21}\left(\frac{12}{7}\right)=-\frac{2}{49}$

$E(X^2)=\frac{12}7$
$E(Y^2)=\frac{51}{14}$

$Var(X)=\frac{12}7-\left(\frac{25}{21}\right)^2=\frac{131}{441}$

$Var(Y)=\frac{69}{98}$

$\rho(X,Y)=\frac{-22/49}{\sqrt{131/441}\sqrt{69/98}}=-0.08924955$

Comment: If possible, have a look at this too. I need a bit of help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129710/a-producer-makes-parts-with-dimensions-between-22-and-28-let-x-be-random

Comment: @Ameer786 Yuup someone beat me to it haha