# Given that the weight of tablets is uniformly distributed between $22$ and $24. $Find the probability that average exceeds $23.5$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Pharma Tablets are produced in large batches. Individual tablets have weight that is uniformly distributed between $22$ and $24$. A sample of $100$ tablets is randomly selected and the average is computed. Find the probability that average exceeds $23.5$.

My working:

Let $W$ be the random variable representing the weight of tablets then since $W$ is uniformly distributed its $pdf$ is given by:

$f(w)=\frac{1}{2}$ ; $\hspace{0.5cm}$ $22<w<24$

Honestly I don't know how to tackle this problem further. A bit of guidance/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about the central limit theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W\sim\text{Uniform}(22,24)$ and has expected value $23$ and variance $\frac 1{12}(b-a)^2=\frac 1{12}(4)=\frac 13$.

The central limit theorem has that $\bar W\sim \text{Normal}\left(23, \frac1{3(100)}\right)=\mathscr N(23, 1/300)$.

So $\Pr(\bar W>23.5)=\Pr\left(Z>\frac{23.5-23}{\sqrt{1/300}}\right)=\Pr(Z>8.660254)=2.353571\times 10^{-18}\approx0$.

Comment: Hey if you have time, can you look at the part $iv$ of the problem in the following link. I am having difficulty in that too. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129604/given-the-following-joint-density-function-find-the-expectation-of-hx-y-2x5?noredirect=1#comment8541855_4129604

Comment: @Ameer786 Posted my solution

Comment: Hey! Thanks alot