# A producer makes Parts with dimensions between $22$ and $28$. Let $X$ be random variable representing dimension of parts then $X$~$N(25,1.5)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

A consumer needs parts with specification $26$ $+/-2$ i.e: parts shorter than $24$ and and longer than $28$ are not acceptable. The producer makes parts with dimension normally distributed with mean $25$ and standard deviation $1.5$. Find the fraction of parts that are acceptable.

My working:

Let $X$ be random variable representing dimension of parts then $X$~$N(25,1.5)$. Hence the $pdf$ of $X$ is given by:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{1.5\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-25}{1.5})^2}$

Rest I don't know how to solve. Honestly I don't understand the other part of question. What is it saying? It is not asking for probability either. Any help and guidance will be helpful.

Comment: A "part" seems to be some "object", the producer produces them abusively, so that a statistics of good (acceptable) and bad objects can be done in practice. We are doing this theoretically, and ask for the fraction of good objects (for the procentual part of produced parts) among all of them. Well, just integrate the density function on the "good interval"...

Comment: On average the fraction of parts that are acceptable will be about the `pnorm(28, 25, 1.5)-pnorm(24, 25, 1.5)`=`0.9772499-0.2524925`=`0.7247574`. It is the area in under the bell curve in the centerish but shifted a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $X$ be random variable representing dimension of parts then
> $X\sim N(25,1.5^{\color{red}2})$. Hence the pdf of $X$ is given by:
>
> $f(x) = \frac{1}{1.5\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-25}{1.5})^2}$

That is correct. I´ve edited the red part only. Let $\Phi(x)$ denote the cdf of the standard normal distribution then it is asked for

$$P(24\leq X\leq 28)=P(X\leq 28)-P(X\leq 24)=\Phi\left(\frac{28-25}{1.5}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{24-25}{1.5}\right)$$

$$=\Phi\left(2\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

$$=\Phi\left(2\right)-\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)$$

$$=\Phi\left(2\right)-1+\Phi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

The values of $\Phi(x)$ can be looked up in the table ([link](https://www.soa.org/globalassets/assets/Files/Edu/2018/exam-srm-tables.pdf)).

Comment: The result is $-0.2774$. Impossible. I found values from table at $2$ to be $0.4772$ and at $2/3$ to be $0.2454$. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Sorry. This table was not the table I wanted to link. Please check the new link.